# passing list en list iterator as pointer c++

Tags: c++, list, function, pointers, iterator

I am giving an list iterator pointer and a list pointer to a function. However I get the error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘SignalGrouper::DoesPeriodExist(std::__cxx11::list<wSignal>*, std::__cxx11::list<wSignal>::iterator&)’
     if((DoesPeriodExist(&donePeriods,it2)==false) && it2->dTime < maxPeriod && it2->dTime > minPeriod)
```

function that calls pointer function:

```
std::list<std::list<wSignal>> SignalGrouper::groupByPeriod (std::list<wSignal> signals, int secs)
{
    std::list<std::list<wSignal>> groupedSignals;
    std::list<wSignal> donePeriods;
    for (std::list<wSignal>::iterator it1=signals.begin(); it1 != signals.end(); ++it1)
    {
        if(DoesPeriodExist(&donePeriods,it1)==false) //check if period is already been grouped
        {
            boost::posix_time::ptime maxPeriod = boost::posix_time::ptime(it1->dTime);
            boost::posix_time::ptime minPeriod = boost::posix_time::ptime(it1->dTime);
            maxPeriod += boost::posix_time::seconds(secs/2);
            minPeriod -= boost::posix_time::seconds(secs/2);
            std::list<wSignal> oneSignalPeriod;
            for (std::list<wSignal>::iterator it2=signals.begin(); it2 != signals.end(); ++it2)
            {
                if((DoesPeriodExist(&donePeriods,it2)==false) && it2->dTime < maxPeriod && it2->dTime > minPeriod) //check if period is already been grouped
                {
                    oneSignalPeriod.push_back(*it2);
                    donePeriods.push_back(*it2);
                }
            }
            groupedSignals.push_back(oneSignalPeriod);
        }
    }
    return groupedSignals;
}
```

The pointer function:

```
bool SignalGrouper::DoesPeriodExist (std::list<wSignal>* signals, wSignal* s)
{
    for (std::list<wSignal>::iterator it1=signals->begin(); it1 != signals->end(); ++it1)
    {
        if((it1->apNr == s->apNr) && (it1->MAC == s->MAC) && (it1->RSSI == s->RSSI) && (it1->dTime == s->dTime))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong. How can I use the pointer function with pointers?

Comment: How come you're passing by pointer?  Passing by reference makes the syntax a lot easier.

Comment: As the error says you're trying to pass an *iterator* and not a *pointer* as the second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are calling has the signature

```
bool SignalGrouper::DoesPeriodExist (std::list<wSignal>* signals, wSignal* s)
```

but on this line

```
DoesPeriodExist(&donePeriods,it1)
```

you are passing it

```
DoesPeriodExist (std::list<wSignal>* signals, std::list<wSignal>::iterator s)
```

To pass the correct type you could say

```
DoesPeriodExist(&donePeriods, &(*it1))
```